# Recordset Update errors when updating sql_variant field

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledb, ado

I'm using C++ and ADO to add data to a SQL Server 2005 database.  When calling the Recordset Update method for a sql_variant column I'm getting the error `DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED` and the error message `Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.`  If the value I'm adding is NULL all works fine and all values going to the fields that are not sql_variant types work.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

[Edit] I have some more information.  The value we are storing is the empty string - ADO appears to want to store this in the sql_variant as a nchar(0), which of course is not a valid SQL data type.  Is there a way to get an empty string in a sql_variant using the ADO batch commands?

Comment: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED indicates that there are several errors and that you must look into the status returned by OLEDB for each of the columns to determine the actual problem.  [Binding Data Values from Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718116(v=vs.85).aspx) provides information about the binding functionality and there is a section on [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722617(v=vs.85).aspx) which provides details on DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only being shown the outer-most error there and as the error suggest you need to check the inner errors to find out the problem.

Apologies, I'm a VB developer but if you loop through the errors on your connection object you should be able to pinpoint the actual error.

From my classic ADO days multiple-step errors usually pointed at trying to stuff something to big into your column, e.g a string thats too big or a number with too high precision.

Hope this helps.

Ed

Comment: Ed, Thanks for the suggestion.  I've been pulled off onto a different project for a few days, so it may be a while before I get a chance to get back to this.